# Do EMBER 1.0 RC require grunt version v0.4.0?

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs

I am planning to use EMBER 1.0 RC, Do we require grunt version  v0.4.0 ??

Answer (score 2):

No, Grunt is not required to use Ember.  You can simply [download](https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js) Ember and include it in your application.

Grunt is a build system that helps you organize your project and perform useful tasks, but is not required.  You can create simple Ember applications without a build system, but build systems are extremely helpful and should be used for any serious projects.

Here is an example JSBin showing a simple Ember application that didn't require a build system: http://jsbin.com/ixupad/1/edit

Here is a good example of an Ember application that uses Grunt: https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences